# How to calculate linear expression value in Excel?

Tags: excel

Say I have.

```
0.2931 = 27.52
0.2277 = 28.33
```

Now I want to know what is for 0.25?

Is there a way to calculate this in Excel easily.

Comment: with 2 data points, fitting is difficult. you can assume a linear fit and interpolate for `0.25`, which will be error-prone. What is your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TREND`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trend-function-e2f135f0-8827-4096-9873-9a7cf7b51ef1):

```
=TREND(B1:B2,A1:A2,A3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use `TREND` as it is posted in @BigBen's answer, but alternative exists with `FORECAST` or `FORECAST.LINEAR`:

```
=FORECAST(A4,B2:B3,A2:A3)
```

[image]